# Stop Salesforce removing https:// from start of web service url

Tags: apex, webservices, urlrewriter

I have set up an apex web service that receives an http get request from an external system with a querystring appended. Salesforce requires the web service endpoint to use HTTPS, which is fine, but in the last few days it has started dropping this unexpectedly.

The endpoint is set up for a text messaging platform that sends SMS delivery receipts to salesforce and then the apex code saves it in the database. Along with every record it saves the URL for reference purposes, and I can see the URL saved starts with https://, however when I directly click the link it rewrites the URL to omit it so it just starts with the subdomain. I have checked and we are not using a URL rewriter class, so I'm guessing this is something Salesforce changed recently. Without the https:// the apex class just returns an error saying unsupported protocol - must use https.

How do I stop salesforce rewriting my urls? Or how do I enable the apex class to accept unsecure http?

Comment: Due to the timing of your problem, this could very likely be a Summer 14 release issue that you'll want to file a support request on for your org/Server Instance with SF Support.